# How to test whether an instance method is called from within another instance method in Grails 3 using Spock

Tags: spock, grails3

Using **Grails 3.2.8** and the **Spock** framework for testing, given the following controller class:

```
class SomeController {
    def doSomething() {
        // do a few things, then:
        someOtherMethod()
    }

    protected void someOtherMethod() {
        // do something here, but I don't care
    }
}
```

How can I test the **doSomething()** method to make sure `someOtherMethod()` is called exactly once?

**This is my attempt that failed:**

```
@TestFor(SomeController)
class SomeControllerSpec extends Specification {
    void "Test that someOtherMethod() is called once inside doSomething()"() {
        when:
        controller.doSomething()

        then:
        1 * controller.someOtherMethod(_)
    } 
}
```

**Error message:**

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * controller.someOtherMethod(_)   (0 invocations)
```

*Note: Imports have been omitted to focus on the problem at hand*

Comment: Are you sure that someOtherMethod() should be a method of the controller and not a service method?  In general, I would say protected methods within controllers can be suspicious.  Without understanding the aim of your methods, it is impossible for me to say.  However, if it were a service method, then using the mocking framework should enable counting of method calls easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that as controller is not a mocked object. Instead, you need to use metaclass like this:

```
@TestFor(SomeController)
class SomeControllerSpec extends Specification {
    void "Test that someOtherMethod() is called once inside doSomething()"() {
        given:
            Integer callsToSomeOtherMethod = 0
            controller.metaClass.someOtherMethod = {
                callsToSomeOtherMethod++
            }
        when:
            controller.doSomething()

        then:
            callsToSomeOtherMethod == 1
    } 
}
```